# What type of trellis do I want to build for fruit bearing vines on the south side of the house?

Tags: construction, gardening

I'm looking at holding up to a ton of vines on a 2 story trellis on including covering up the chimney on the side of the house, in order to keep a lot of summer heat off the house, and was wondering what type I should build, and to stand up to the weight during the summer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice comes down to personal preference, how much you want to spend and the amount of upkeep. For a large heavy vine(s) like you describe I would go with wrought iron. It will last decades with no real maintenance. It is also one of the more expensive ways to go but in the long run it is worth the cost in my opinion.